# jquery 1.4.2 tabs problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm new to this forum and jquery, recently i've updated new version jquery 1.4.2 after that, initially while loading the web page my first and default tab showing the last tab content, once we clicked on any tab then the problem solved automatically, again if we load the page again the same problem ocurrs.

following is the code i used

```
$('.main').tabs();




<div class="main">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab1">Title Page</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">Manuscript</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">Figures and Tabels</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="tab1">Tab 1</div>
<div class="tab2">Tab 2</div>
<div class="tab3">Tab 3</div>

</div>
```

But the same working perfect in the previous version, any help will be appreciated.

Regards
Bala

Comment: What jQuery plugin are you using for your tabs, and what version of jQuery were you using before? (Also, I'm guessing the missing quote in your first line isn't actually in the code, since it worked before. Is that correct?)

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.4 UI 1.8, you are correct that is a typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of jQuery UI? (1.8)
jQuery UI 1.7.3 doesn't support jQuery 1.4

**Demo**: http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs_3/
**Download**: http://jqueryui.com/download